# Is there a word for a person who avoids their responsibilities?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who avoids their responsibilities by disregarding them and just continue doing other things?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Your question is lacking in info. Could you elaborate more on what you mean, providing some sample sentences where you might want to use the word and maybe with examples and research that you have done?

Comment: Related: [*How to say it: Fleeing from responsibility*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298057/how-to-say-it-fleeing-from-responsibility/298058#298058)

Answer (score 9):

To **shirk** is to avoid or neglect a responsibility.

So, a person who shirks is a **shirker**.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shirker

Answer (score 6):

**Slacker** might be a good choice: *a person who shirks work or obligation; especially :  one who evades military service in time of war* ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slacker))

Answer (score 2):

A ***procrastinator***.

> **Procrastinate**: to be slow or late about doing something that should be done : to delay doing something until a later time because you do not want to do it, because you are lazy, etc. ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procrastinate))